# php : file_put_contents error

Tags: php, android

I'm using file put content to save my image to the server, but I get an error and the image is not saved .

I am getting the `base64` string from android app, I decode it and  pass it on for saving. My php script is in this location (example):

```
www.aaa.com/test
```

I want to save the photos to:

```
www.aaa.com/test/photos
```

What I have:

```
$name = "image123.png";
$data = base64_decode($fldPostPhoto);
file_put_contents("photos/".$name,$data);
```

Comment: You should post complete php script. And complete Android code.

Comment: 500 server error is no file_put_contents error.

Comment: if i comment file_put_contents("photos/".$name,$data); then

Comment: then the php script works properly, and it executes my remaining

Comment: I'm sure that `file_put_contents` can't save to remote locations perhaps you can visualise it based on internal local paths of your server.

Comment: ok .. what should be my exact path to be provided to file_put_content to save the image. Also i can save the image in the folder manually using filezilla so then I must have the right to write files to the folder .. right ?

Comment: so if file_put_contents can't save to remote locations  , then how to I save the images to my remote location ??

Comment: @SohanKumar you're using path `"photos/somename.png"` , this is a relative path to the current working directory (which you can check what it is using `getcwd()` ). It may not actually be the script directory or the root directory so make sure it's either correct, or you use absolute paths (based on `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` perhaps?)

Comment: thanks... let me try